# Turn off Windows Phone keys vibration

Tags: settings, vibration

I want to turn off vibration when pressing the back, home and search keys.

Is it possible to do this in Windows Phone 8+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn this off in the touch settings:

1. Go to Settings

2. Navigate to Touch

You should be able to see these options

[image]

Comment: This feature is also available on WP8. In fact, the screen you posted is *exactly* the same on my Lumia with GDR3.

Comment: Note this works on Nokia Lumia phones only. I'm not able to see it in my HTC.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, my bad! :)

Answer (score 8):

This feature is available since WP 8.0 Black update, under Settings → Touch.

[image]

Comment: The Lumia Black update only applies to Nokia phones. What about other brands? Was this feature part of GDR3 or Black?

Comment: I'll check HTC with gdr3